# Массовый перенос постов между форумами Bbpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, bbpress

Была задача перенести массово посты из одного форума в другой. Например: форум Процессоры в нем форум Intel и форум AMD, необходимо было перенести все посты из AMD и Intel в процессоры. Я искал, но из доступных инструментов там был только модуль, который обновлялся последний раз несколько лет назад, он не видел всех форумов сайта. Подсмотрел в его коде принцип, нужно было изменить у постов родительский форум. Сделал примерно следующее, запросом SQL:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_parent` = REPLACE(post_parent, '67234', '67233' ) ;
```

Все перенеслось, однако если оставлять ответы в перенесенных топиках, то метаинформация родительского форума не обновляется. Имею в виду информаци  о том кто оставил последний пост и сколько времени назад. В этом примере у форума "Процессоры".
Я так понял нужно еще что то сделать для корректной работы этой функции? Может у кого то был подобный опыт?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение на форуме плагина, оказывается проблема известна. В теме есть ссылка на модуль, который принудительно обновляет мета информафию. https://bbpress.org/forums/topic/freshness-doesnt-seem-to-update-as-quickly-any-more/page/6/